# Sort file output from a reddit text file by Post Score?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I have this project where a search on a text file. I have the search set up by a keyword in this case the keyword: "bug" and "Bug". So the program currently outputs the only the lines that have the keyword but I also want it to out put by post score in descending order from highest to lowest score.

Here is the code in main:

```
int main() {
string search;
ifstream inFile;
string line;

inFile.open("RedditTestPage.txt");

if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
string searchLow = "bug";
string searchCap = "Bug";


size_t pos;
while (inFile.good())
{
    getline(inFile, line);
    pos = line.find(searchLow);
    if (pos !=string::npos)
    {

        cout << line << endl;

    }
    pos = line.find(searchCap);
    if (pos != string::npos)
    {

        cout << line << endl;

    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

and I am reading from a text file identical to this:

100 The Most Extreme Biomes

21 Best Screen Shot

11 Found Atlantis

210 Found a critical bug

1205 Production Bug

41 Amazing Screen shot

12 Does anybody else?

Comment: While `while (inFile.good())` is better than `while (!inFile.eof())` it still suffers  from the fact that it tests for validity BEFORE reading the data. `getline(inFile, line);` may still fail making `pos = line.find(searchLow);` questionable.

Comment: Quick simplification: If you use `std::transform` and `tolower` to convert the search key to lower case, you eliminate the need for multiple calls to `find`

Comment: What do you mean by post score? I'm not seeing any code to handle this.

Comment: @user4581301 Basically in the text file each line has a number to the left, I want to sort the output by the numbers on left from highest to lowest

Comment: Start by reading that first number on the line into a `std::vector` and using `std::sort` to sort the vector. Then make a data structure that maps the number to its line and make a vector of that data structure for every line that contains the search key. Sort that vector according to the number.

Comment: Ok, can you code example on how to write that so I can better understand?